# problem of Taylor's approximation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, vector-analysis

Let be $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ twice differentiable, such that $$f(1,0)=2,\quad  \nabla f(1,0)=  \begin{bmatrix}
    0   \\
    1   \\
    \end{bmatrix} \quad \nabla^2f(1,0)=\begin{bmatrix}
     1 & -1 \\
    -1 &  0 \\
    \end{bmatrix} $$ 
and consider the initial value problem

$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y), \quad y(1)=0,\quad x \in \mathbb R.$

Determine the Taylor approximation of order 3 for the solution $y(x)$ in a neighborhood of $x(1)$

I have doubts with the solutions, I do not know which is fine. Please can you help me

SOL:

I did these two ways, I do not know which is fine.

Sol 1

Taylor's approximation of order 3 for the solution y(x) in a neighborhood of x(1)

$y(x)\approx y(1)+\frac{dy(1)}{dx}(x-1)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{dy^2(1)}{dx^2}(x-1)^2+\frac{1}{6}\frac{dy^3(1)}{dx^3}(x-1)^3$

of hypothesis we have

$y(1)=0$ $\quad  \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad  \quad$... (1)

$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y) \quad  \Rightarrow  \quad \frac{dy(1)}{dx}=f(1,0)=2 $ $\quad  \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad  \quad$... (2)

$\frac{dy^2}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{dx})= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f(x,y))\quad  \Rightarrow  \quad \frac{dy^2}{dx^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f(x,y))=0$ (of $\nabla f(1,0)$ ) $\quad\quad  $ (3)

$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy^2}{dx^2})=\frac{d}{dx}( \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f(x,y)))\quad  \Rightarrow  \quad \frac{dy^3}{dx^3}=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}(f(x,y))=1$ (of$ \nabla ^2 f(1,0)$ ) $\quad\quad  $ (4)

substituting in the Taylor's approximation of order 3, we get

$y(x)=2(x-1)+\frac{1}{6}(x-1)^3$

Sol 2.

of hypothesis we have

$y(1)=0$ $\quad  \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad  \quad$... (1´)

$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y) \quad  \Rightarrow  \quad \frac{dy(1)}{dx}=f(1,0)=2 $ $\quad  \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad  \quad$... (2´)

$\frac{dy^2}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{dx})= \frac{d}{dx}(f(x,y))= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x.y)\frac{dx}{dx}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x.y)\frac{dy}{dx}$

$\quad  \Rightarrow  \quad \frac{dy^2}{dx^2}=0.1+1.2=2$ (of $\nabla f(1,0)$ ) $\quad\quad  $ (3´)

$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy^2}{dx^2})=\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x.y)+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x.y)\frac{dy}{dx})=\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)) + \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x.y)f(x,y))$

applying chain rule we get

$\frac{dy^3}{dx^3}= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}(f(x,y))+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y).f(x,y)+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y}(f(x,y)).f(x,y)+\frac{\partial }{\partial y}(f(x,y)).\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(f(x,y))$

$\quad  \Rightarrow  \quad \frac{dy^3}{dx^3}=1+1.2+(-1).2+1.0=1$

(of$ \nabla ^2 f(1,0)$ ) $\quad\quad  $ (4´)

substituting in the Taylor's approximation of order 3, we get

$y(x)=2(x-1)+(x-1)^2+\frac{1}{6}(x-1)^3$

I have doubts with the solutions, I do not know which is fine. Please can you help me

Answer (score 1):

The second variant looks good.

In the first variant you wrongly change a total derivative into a partial derivative, while in the second variant that is correctly handled.